# Can hashCode() have dynamically changeable content?

Tags: java

In my implementation, I have a class A which overrides equals(Object) and hashCode(). But I have a small doubt that is, while adding the instance of A to HashSet/HashMap the value of the hashCode() is x, after sometime the value of the same hashCode() changed to y. Will it effect anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hash code mustn't change *after it's been added to a map / set*. It's okay for it to change before that, although it generally makes the type easier to work with if it *doesn't* change.

If the hash code changes, the key won't be found in the map / set, as even if it ends up in the same bucket, the hash code will be changed first.

Answer (score 3):

When the return value of `hashCode()` or `equals()` changes while the object is contained in `HashMap`/`HashSet` etc., the behavior is undefined (you could get all kinds of strange behavior). So one must avoid such mutation of keys while the object is contained in such collections etc.

It is considered best to use only immutable objects for keys (or place them in a `HashSet` etc.). In fact python for example, does not allow mutable objects to be used as keys in maps. It is permissive/common to use mutable objects as keys in Java, but in such case it is advisable to make such objects "effectively immutable". I.e. do not change the state of such objects at all after instantiation.

To give an example, using a list as a key in a Map is usually considered okay, but you should avoid mutating such lists at any point of your application to avoid getting bitten by nasty bugs.

As long as you don't change the return value of `hashCode()` and `equals()` while the objects are in the container, you should be ok on paper. But one could easily introduce nasty, hard to find bugs by mistake so it's better to avoid the situation altogether.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that we are talking about the key, and not the value. The hashcode of the value object can change.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the hash code of an object must not change during its lifetime. If it does, you need to notify the container (if that's possible); otherwise you <strike>will</strike> can get wrong results.

**Edit:** As pointed out, it depends on the container. Obviously, if the container never uses your `hashCode` or `equals` methods, nothing will go wrong. But as soon as it tries to compare things for equality (all maps and sets), you'll get yourself in trouble.

Comment: Is there any method to notify for the content change in HashSet/HashMap?

Comment: @Jessu: Nope, not in Java's HashSet/HashMap. You'd need to remove the object, change its hash code, then add it back.

Comment: The hash code *can* change during an object's lifetime - it's just that if it's already been added to a map/set, you'll end up in trouble. It's fine to (say) create an ArrayList, add items to it, and then use that as a key in a HashMap *so long as it's never changed afterwards*.

Comment: @Jon: I think that was implicit in the question, otherwise worrying about hash codes is a bit pointless to begin with.

Comment: @Mehrdad: It's specified in the question (not implicit at all) but your *answer* is overly broad. Your answer suggests that only immutable types should override hashCode at all. You need to be much more careful with mutable types which override hashCode, and understand the consequences of doing so, but it's valid to do so and doesn't violate the rules in the Javadoc.

Comment: @Mehrdad @JonSkeet: the actual rule is 'Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified.' Javadoc for Object.hashCode().

Comment: @EJP: Exactly. In this case, I'm assuming that the information used for equality comparisons *has* been changed, so it's okay for hashCode to change in terms of the *implementation*... it's just not okay in terms of its *usage*, when the object is already a key in a map/set.

Comment: @JonSkeet: quite, and the documentation for Set and Map state that the behaviour is undefined if the object mutates as observed by equals(). So it mustn't mutate while in the map, and therefore its hashCode mustn't change either.

Comment: @Jon: I still honestly don't understand what's wrong with assuming that the object was being changed *after* it was added to a hashtable. The question seems a bit pointless to me otherwise. I have no idea what the Javadocs say (I never even looked at them when answering this question), but from a CS standpoint, I'm failing to see why this is a bad assumption.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, the object *is* only being changed after it was added to a hashtable in the qusetion. But your first statement claims that an object's hash code must not change *during its lifetime*. That's a very different thing - far broader than the scope of the question - and an incorrect statement.

Comment: @Jon: Ah, I see what you mean now. I wasn't using "lifetime" in a strict sense, but if you look at it that way, then yeah, it might not be completely right. (I'm not quite sure if it's wrong in the context of *Java* either, though -- @EJP's note of the Java specs seems to say otherwise: it says *nothing* about the *caller* of `hashCode`. It seems like the Java spec is tougher than the normal hashing rules.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Many people answered the question here, I just want to say an analogy. Hash code is something like address in hash-based collection:

Imagine you check in a hotel by your name "Mike", after that you change your name to "GreatMike" on check-paper. Then when someone looks for you by your name "Mike", he cannot find you anymore.