# How to keep the hash code of an object consistent during the applications runtime?

Tags: java, hashcode

Imagine we have the following simple *mutable* class:

```
public class Point {
  private int x;
  private int y;

  ...

  public void addToX(int delta) {
    x += delta;
  }

  public void addToY(int delta) {
    y += delta;
  }
}
```

Overriding the `hashCode` method using the only class field `x` and `y` will not work, because the values can change during runtime when the `addToX`/`addToY` method is called.

So I was wondering what an appropriate implementation of `hashCode` would be for *mutable* classes?

Comment: This is a contradictory goal.  If you want the hashcode to be a function of the object's value, and if the object's value may change, then you'll have to accept that the hashcode may change.

Comment: Calculate the hash code the first time and store it in a field in the object.  Use that value on subsequent calls.

Comment: Why don't accept the original hashcode ?

Comment: The hashCode is not supposed to stay constant. It's only supposed to be consistent with equals() (i.e. two equal objects must have the same hashCode).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you use the x and y fields in the implementation of Point#equals(Point p) there is no need to keep Point#hashCode() consistent over the lifetime of an object of type Point.

Indeed, the javadoc for class java.lang.Object states for hashCode() that

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>   execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>   return the same integer

but there's a confinement right after that :

> , provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is
>   modified

see also [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Implementing the hash code using the class fields x and y (and also using them for the equals method) seems to be ok for the javadoc for class java.lang.Object. But isn't it wrong anyway, since a changing hash code can cause problems when using a HashSet for example?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood: no. What would be wrong would be to store instances of a mutable class in a HashSet, and modifying them after. But that's not the fault of the mutable class. That's the fault of the code using it.

Comment: @JBNizet : good point. To complete this answer here are two useful links for anybody wanting to know more about the effects of changing hashcodes of objects after they have been stored in hash-based containers : see here  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013631/can-hashcode-have-dynamically-changeable-content and here :[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174233/changing-hashcode-of-object-stored-in-hash-based-collection. Note however that these issues don't imply that you generally cannot have mutable fields in hashCode() and equals().

Answer (score 2):

You imply in your question that the class doesn't really represent a static point because you can change the x and y values.  That's why a hash code based on the x and y value seems wrong to you.  I think what the class really represents is a position whose x and y values can change.  In that case, there's an attribute you're implying that is the identification of that position (e.g. the position of car 37) and this identification does not change even though the x/y values do change.  You want to define this uniquely-valued attribute, add it to your class and base your hash code (and equals) implementation on that attribute